# Git show multiple commits combined

Tags: git

How would I do something like `git show commit1 commit2` but display the output as one combined commit, ie, review multiple commits as one?

Comment: i would create a script to take the commits as input, create an array, and loop through that and echo the subject & body to stdout

Comment: @Todd in what way it's better than just `for commit in commit1 commit2; do git --no-pager show $commit; done` ?

Comment: @phd your script foo is better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

How do you want to combine commit messages? I don't think there is a reasonable way.

If you want to combine just diffs then use `git diff` instead of `git show`:

```
git diff commit1 commit2
```

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--merge-baseltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203).

Comment: Hi @phd. In this context, I'd be fine with disregarding the commit messages and reviewing a combined patch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare your current state against 2 commits ago, run this:

```bash
git diff 'HEAD^^..'
```

For 4 commits ago, change it to

```bash
git diff 'HEAD^^^^..'
```

Answer (score -1):

Ended up doing it like this:

```
git checkout -b tmp <commit0_sha>~
git cherry-pick <commit0_sha>
git cherry-pick --strategy=recursive -X theirs <commitn_sha>
git rebase -i `git merge-base tmp main`
git show
```

Would be amazing if there's a more terse way.